# Read Attributes of SVG-Elements in HTML via JS

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, svg, no-framework

I have the following markup (HTML with native SVG):

```
<!doctype html>
   <!-- ...    
        html-Elements 
        ... --> 
   <svg version="1.1" ... >
        <defs> <circle id="infop" cx="0" cy="0" r="9" /> </defs>
        <!-- ... 
             svg Elements
             ... --> 
        <svg> <!-- to have separate coordinate-system -->
            <g id="outSvg"></g>
        </svg>
    ...
```

A js-method outputs a line and several `<use href="infotop">` Elements to `#outSvg` (to become a graph).
The `<use>` Elements have onmouseover-Events to show tooltips.

**Now, when it comes to retrieving the coordinates in the `onmouseover-function` of the `<use>` i run into problems:**

I tried the following different approaches to retrieve the values:

```
function showInfo(evt){

    console.log("target: "+evt.target);
    console.log("AttrNS: "+evt.target.getAttributeNS(null,"x"));
    console.log("Attrib: "+evt.target.getAttribute("x"));
    console.log("basVal: "+evt.target.x.baseVal.value);
    console.log("corrEl: "+evt.target.correspondingUseElement.x.baseVal.value);
```

producing the following output:

```
    //target -> ** [object SVGUseElement] in FF, in all other browsers: [object SVGElementInstance])
    //AttrNS -> Works only in FF
       // * Uncaught TypeError: Object #<SVGElementInstance> has no method 'getAttributeNS'
    //Attrib -> Works only in FF
       // * Uncaught TypeError: Object #<SVGElementInstance> has no method 'getAttribute'
    //basVal -> works only in FF
       // * Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'baseVal' of undefined
    //corrEl -> fails in FF but works in Ch, O and IE
```

Browsers:FF10, Ch16, O11.61, IE9

**Question:**

Why is `getAttribute()` failing in the other browsers? Am I missing something important? Is there a consistent way to retrieve the values **crossbrowser**?  (Besides via a switch between `evt.target.x` and `evt.target.correspondingUseElement.x`)

*important: vanilla js only, and I know about browserswitches, thats not the point! I'll provide a fiddle if needed, as soon as i find the time. Finally - thank you for reading this!*

EDIT: * added the js-errors

EDIT2: ** FF returns another Object than the other browsers

Comment: Seems you already found a way. Use either `target.x` or `target.correspondingUseElement.x`. Should not be difficult to create a wrapper function for SVG attribute access.

Comment: Well, I find your solution rather unsatisfying...

Comment: @Christoph, people spend their own time to try to help you FOR FREE. Shouldn't you be grateful?

Comment: @Allen I explicitely asked if there is a way that works crossbrowser without using a wrapper function - am I not allowed to express my feelings about an unsatisfactory answer then (which suggests a solution I already figured out by myself anyway)? Erik for example provided some very useful information, that's why I upvoted his answer and explicitely thanked him.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, after reading [Erik Dahlström's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9275695/read-attributes-of-svg-elements-in-html-via-js#9301408), I noticed that FF behaves incorrectly. It should return an Element-Instance instead of the Use-Element directly.

I use the following code now:

```
var el = (evt.target.correspondingUseElement)?evt.target.correspondingUseElement:evt.target;

console.log(el.getAttribute("x"));
```

This way I can retrieve the attributes via [`getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) consistently in all browsers.

Comment: I think for cross browser solution it is better not to use <use> elements if you want to have access via JS. You can always replace them in JS with normal elements.

Comment: @Bharata what exactly is causing cross browser issues in your opinion? I haven't touched SVG in a while, so I'm not sure which problem you are referring to, but I'm happy to include it in the answer - the question is six years old after all;-)

Comment: Because for example in IE10 I had the problem with getting from attributes of <use> elements. And with `evt.target.correspondingUseElement` I did not solve this problem. I have replaced all <use> elements with <path> elements and the problem was gone. I have nothing against your answer. I wrote my comment only as a hint.

Comment: @Bharata Thank you for your comment! This is exactly how the SO community should work! If I have time, I will look what exactly happened there (`<use>` support being dropped in IE10? As you can see from my question it "use"d 
 (hehe) to work in IE9). On the other hand, IE does not have too much relevance anymore anyway...

Answer (score 2):

can you try this? `evt.target.getAttributeNode("x").nodeValue` . I tried this in safari,chrome,Firefox its working fine.

Comment: also throws `TypeError: no such method`. I think I'll prepare a fiddle for that.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know Firefox doesn't support SVGElementInstance.

Here are a couple of tests for SVGElementInstance from the w3c SVG 1.1 Second Edition testsuite to verify:

- [struct-dom-12-b](http://dev.w3.org/SVG/profiles/1.1F2/test/harness/htmlObjectApproved/struct-dom-12-b.html)
- [struct-dom-14-f](http://dev.w3.org/SVG/profiles/1.1F2/test/harness/htmlObjectApproved/struct-dom-14-f.html)
- [struct-dom-15-f](http://dev.w3.org/SVG/profiles/1.1F2/test/harness/htmlObjectApproved/struct-dom-15-f.html)

What you should do is to provide a fallback solution if the SVGElementInstance isn't there, which is easy enough to detect, e.g:

```
if (elm.correspondingUseElement) {
  /* elm is a used instance, not a real element */
} else {
  /* fallback solution */
}
```

If the element is an SVGElementInstance it will have the `correspondingUseElement` property, otherwise it won't have it. Normal svg elements will not have this property, only used instances will have it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `evt.target.getAttributeNS(evt.target.parent.namespaceURI,"x")` ?

Comment: `evt.target.getAttributeNS(null,"x");` does the same and doesn't change the fact, that  the svgElement seems to lack the according method in the other browsers.